# "Google cloud shell is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting in a few minutes." error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried `&cloudshell=true` in the end of URL, doesn't work. Cleared cookies, tried Incognito mode also doesn't work. Tried opening on Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge also doesn't work. Turned off all the firewalls and still doesn't work. Need help.

Comment: Try connecting in a few minutes.

Comment: I've been trying for days.

Comment: Please let me know if your access to the cloud shell was working before? Or is this the first time you are having this issue. If it was working before then there might be some issues with your account permission , you may need to contact your administrator to assign you the right [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#authorization). There is a similar case on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753235/i-keep-getting-google-cloud-shell-is-temporarily-unavailable-try-connecting-in) where the issue resolved after assigning the right account.

Comment: Nothing works. Just downloaded Google Cloud SDK shell and used it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback,From the description, it is not clear why you are getting the error.I suggest creating a [Private issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) as the issue requires inspection of your project and account information.